# sailsJS http request

Tags: angular, api, sails.js

can someone help with making http request call to weather api using sailsJS

```
    var http = require('http');

    var rs = "Someone";
    var options = {
        hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
        port: 80,
        path: '/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=3188582&units=metric&appid=(MY_APP_ID)',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(response) {
        sails.log.debug('log:'+response);
        rs = response;
        res.ok(rs);
    });
```

It should return at least something to the controller but there is a some kind of an error, it won't even display page. I only get "This site can’t be reached" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

and use it like this..

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

rp({
   method: 'GET',
   uri: 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily',
   qs: {
       id: 3188582,
       units: metric,
       appid=(MY_APP_ID)
   },
   json: true
}).then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```